# Convert an unknown format of database query into MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, converters

I got it from [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities)

And this is how the data looks like:

```
Country,City,AccentCity,Region,Population,Latitude,Longitude
ad,aixas,Aixàs,06,,42.4833333,1.4666667
ad,aixirivali,Aixirivali,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixirivall,Aixirivall,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixirvall,Aixirvall,06,,42.4666667,1.5
ad,aixovall,Aixovall,06,,42.4666667,1.4833333
ad,andorra,Andorra,07,,42.5,1.5166667
```

I want to convert the structure of this unknown type data into MySQL query language so that I can insert it into my MySQL database. Is it possible?

The data is about 145 MB!! I can paste the whole data code if required.

Alternative required solution: What should I do to insert it in my database?

Comment: What is your DB structure for import?

Comment: Looks like simple comma-separated value (CSV) data to me; not something I'd consider "unknown"

Comment: SQL, like:

INSERT INTO table_name (id,etc) VALUES (1,etc);

Comment: I have no idea about CSV, so it's unknown to me! @MarkBaker

Comment: What should I do to insert it in my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that looks like a regular CSV to me, and PHPMyAdmin is capable of handling such format in the import menu

[image: CSV PHPMyAdmin options]

The problem I see there is that you've got a large file to upload and most php configurations won't allow you such big upload. Why not try it with, say, the first 1000 lines of your file?

Comment: Should I create the 'Country, City, Region' fields in the table or will the query do it for me?

Comment: This is how it looks like in my XAMPP database: http://gyazo.com/aaf35fa5092904c43d6347e4cab4a808

What parameter changes do I make?

Comment: If you use phpmyadmin and check "the first line of the file contains the table columns names" then you don't need to manually create the table.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your XAMMP version. I'd give a try with the CSV WITH LOAD DATA first, but if you go with CSV option, then use comma as default separator and leave blank the enclosed and escaped fields. You should also manually enter your field names in the last input. (comma separated)